# Java speech recognition API

Tags: java, speech-recognition

I am currently developing an Android application where I am required to implement speech recognition.

Could you suggest a link where I could find a Java speech recognition API?

Answer (score 21):

**[CMU Sphinx Open Source Toolkit For Speech Recognition](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/)**

**[CMU Sphinx Open Source Toolkit For Speech Recognition Android](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid)**

Answer (score 6):

Please read these articles they contain  good tuts on `Speech Recognition`

**1)** [This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XGvUCx9FBS4) **-** A video tutorial from `Youtube.`

**2)** [This](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/08/android-voice-recognition-tutorial.html) **-** A tutorial which goes through the process of creating a app which uses `SpeechRecognition.`

**3)** [This](https://github.com/rakeshcusat/Code4Reference/tree/master/AndroidProjects/VoiceRecognitionExample) **-** A `opensource` `Voice recognition` project...

Comment: 3rd = 1st but written

Answer (score 3):

I would advise the `android.speech` package:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html