# Voice to text conversion with JSAPI

Tags: java, voice-recognition

If anybody knows about 'voice to text' conversion using java, please give me some knowledge.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as i know, the way to use this is the JSR 113 Java Speech API 2.0

The advantage in using would be the offline functionality without an internet connection.

But unfortunately the leading company seems to terminated their intentions for this project, the homepage is down (http://www.conversay.com).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at answers to [`a similar question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/143390/java-text-to-speech-engines-overview), the prospects don't look encouraging.  However I did find something despite the relative dearth of activity around **JSAPI** implementations.

Take a look at the [Java Wrapper for Cepstral TTS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/java-cepstral/) project on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net).  It relies upon the [Cepstral TTS engine](https://www.cepstral.com/downloads/) which is available for several languages and speakers as well versions targeting desktop, mobile and telephony server deployments.

*Disclosure:  I have no relationship to Cepstral nor have I used their products.*

Answer (score 1):

For speech recognition, see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034925/java-speech-recognition-api). If not using android, you might want to check out [CMUSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/).