# speech to text conversion on Labview

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, labview

I am planning to build a speech to text convertor on Labview and later port the same to myRio board. I am new to this field and I donno where to start with. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Since you're planning to use myRIO, you'll probably need a C-based library.  I haven't used [CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/), but it seems to be a common [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6152186) and it has a C library.

You'll find documentation on developing with the myRIO [here](http://sine.ni.com/psp/app/doc/p/id/psp-1166/lang/en).